# Setting build options for kernel

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, makefile

Can I programaticaly generate a `.config` file before building a kernel, with some pre-selected values (say `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO` for example). Something like `make defconfig CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y && make`?

Comment: Some tags are dependent on other tags, so configuring like that are not a good idea.  The Kconfig files make sure some options are available/not available based on other kernel config options that are currently enabled/disabled.

Comment: @PeterL. Yes, that's why I'm asking if there is any way of doing it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this with the default config for your architecture together with `make allnoconfig`. What you should do is copy the default config for your architecture to, say `my-custom.config`, add the symbols that you want, and run `make KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG=my-custom.config allnoconfig`. In full, for x86_64:

```
$ cp arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig my-custom.config
$ cat "CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y" >> my-custom.config
$ make KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG=my-custom.config allnoconfig
```

This will configure it such that everything is turned off except for the things in your default config (which includes the architecture default config plus the pre-selected values that you've enabled) and their dependencies. See [the kconfig documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig.txt) for details.

**edit** After testing this out myself, this isn't quite right, as it doesn't pick up up default values that aren't contained in your architecture's defaults. Instead, you probably want to generate a default config for your architecture with `make defconfig`, add your specific tweaks to that, and then do the allnoconfig trick with that:

```
$ make KCONFIG_CONFIG=my-custom.config defconfig
$ echo "CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y" >> my-custom.config
$ make KCONFIG_ALLCONFIG=my-custom.config allnoconfig
```

Comment: Some options pre-select ther options. Will this trick handle that?

Comment: @alexandernst This is the equivalent of doing `make defconfig` followed by using one of the other methods to enable the extra options that you want on top of `make defconfig`. It should select any options that doing that would. I don't believe it will select any new default values that are now available based on your new config option; those you'll have to do manually, I believe. Why don't you try it and see if it does what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .config with the desired options, then run `make oldconfig`. This will take all the options it can find in the config and ask you for the unset options. Alternatively you can run `make olddefconfig` which does the same but instead of asking, uses the default value for options it didn't find.